# How to export test cases including steps from excel to Azure?

Tags: excel, azure, file-upload, tfs, testcase

How to export test cases from excel to Azure ?

Tried Team foundation Server but not able to add steps and Summary? please provide info if anyone can assist on this

Comment: Could give a little more context? What is a "test case"? What do you mean by export? Import into what part of Azure?

Comment: Others cannot help you if we do not understand your problem thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to copy test cases and test steps from an existing Excel to TFS/Azure DevOps, you can refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops#q-can-i-copy-test-cases-and-test-steps-from-an-existing-excel-worksheet

> Copy the columns from Excel that you want to use for the title,
>   action, and expected results fields. No column formatting, other than
>   multiline, is copied from the worksheet. Paste these columns into the
>   **grid view**, edit if necessary, and save them. (This is supported only
>   with Internet Explorer and Chrome browsers.)

[image]